# fatal: parameter "smtpd_recipient_restrictions" in maillog

Tags: postfix

I am seeing this in my maillog:

```
fatal: parameter "smtpd_recipient_restrictions": specify at least one working instance of: check_relay_domains, reject_unauth_destination, reject, defer or defer_if_permit
```

However in my main.cf file I have this:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, check_relay_domains, reject_unauth_destination, reject
```

Can anyone explain what the problem is here please?

Answer (score 2):

This will not be your answer, but this is the answer that got it working on the unit I was troubleshooting. Maybe four years late it can still help someone else in the future.

In the `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file, we needed to add in the following line:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject
```

A `systemctl restart postfix` and a test has found us to seem to be in working order after that.

Comment: Your solution removed the error message in my logs. However I'm still not able to receive mail. All mails from the outside are now rejected. I also tried `smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject` instead of your solution, but it still rejects all mails.

Answer (score 1):

ok - I found it - it's referring to the setting in my master.cf - doh!

Comment: Which setting? Other people may have the same error message, this doesn't help them out very much.