# Postfix rejects all outside mails

Tags: postfix, dovecot

## My Problem

I tried setting up my own mail server using postfix and dovecot. I used [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-e-mail-server-with-dovecot) to get started. My end goal is to have virtual mailboxes like [in this follow-up tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-email-server-with-dovecot-dynamic-maildirs-and-lmtp). (In case you do not want to read those just refer to the config files on the bottom of my post.)

However I'm stuck with Postfix rejecting all mails from the outside.

## What I tried

First I tried setting everything up like in the first tutorial to get postfix to send and receive mail for a local user while using dovecot for the mailboxes.
However if I follow every instruction line by line I end up with the following error in my mail logs:

```
Sep  2 00:07:43 servername postfix/smtpd[6362]: fatal: in parameter smtpd_relay_restrictions or smtpd_recipient_restrictions, specify at least one working instance of: reject_unauth_destination, defer_unauth_destination, reject, defer, defer_if_permit or check_relay_domains
```

According to this [serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1065651/294099) I need to add the following line to `main.cf`. (Which to be fair is pretty much what the error message told me to do):

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject
```

With this adjustment postfix stops giving me errors. Using the `mail` command from debian's `bsd-mailx` I'm able to send mail to outside mail addresses and to users on my server. I'm also able to receive mails from users on my server. Mails from outside mail addresses to my local user (root in this case) are all rejected though:

```
Sep  2 00:09:45 servername postfix/smtpd[6580]: connect from bigmailhoster.com[12.34.56.78]
Sep  2 00:09:45 servername postfix/smtpd[6580]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from bigmailhoster.com[12.34.56.78]: 554 5.7.1 <root@myserver.com>: Recipient address rejected: Access denied; from=<myname@bigmailhoster.com> to=<root@myserver.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<bigmailhoster.com>
Sep  2 00:09:45 servername postfix/smtpd[6580]: disconnect from bigmailhoster.com[12.34.56.78] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 quit=1 commands=5/7
```

However I figured that I probably need to set `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` instead of relay restrictions like I did in my `master.cf`.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
```

Unfortunately this changes nothing. After I restart postfix all outside mails are still getting rejected.

## My Config Files

In the end my config for postfix is the following:

### main.cf

```
~# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
inet_interfaces = all
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mail.myserver.com, myserver.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = mail.myserver.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = myserver.com
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.myserver.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.myserver.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

### master.cf

```
~# postconf -M
smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog    unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
submission inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o syslog_name=postfix/submission -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=no -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
```

### dovecot.conf

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but this is dovecot's config:

```
~# doveconf -n
# 2.3.4.1 (f79e8e7e4): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.4 ()
# OS: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Debian 10.12 
# Hostname: servername
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mail_privileged_group = mail
passdb {
  args = %s
  driver = pam
}
plugin {
  autocreate = Trash
  autocreate2 = Sent
  autosubscribe = Trash
  autosubscribe2 = Sent
}
protocols = imap
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.myserver.com/fullchain.pem
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = " autocreate"
}
```

Comment: Look at the messages logged when postfix starts up. It will emit a warning when you are using backwards-compatible defaults. You can then set `compatibility_level`, confirming you have checked your (year 2013) configuration and opting out of backwards-compatible defaults that caused the initial warning in the first place.

Comment: @anx Thx. That did the trick. I had to remove `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` again (following exactly the tutorial), but add `compatibility_level=2` to `main.cf`. Now everything works. I had no idea about compatibility defaults.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to anx's comment I was able to solve my issue.

Postfix has changed some defaults over the years. To keep old config files like the one from the tutorial working postfix has introduced backwards-compatible defaults in version 3.0. In order for this to work the setting `compatibility_level` must be set to the correct version of postfix.

In my case I needed the defaults for Postfix 2.x. So this is the change I had to make to my `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
```

```
compatibility_level=2
```

For further reading have a look at this: http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html